# angularjs routing is not working no error found

Tags: angularjs-routing

what seems to be wrong here i dont get any error but at the same time no progress in routing. .

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Angular App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myAngularApp/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myAngularApp/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/myAngularApp/css/mainpage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<h1> this is index.html </h1>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

mainpage.js // where my controller is

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) { 
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'index.html'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl : 'homepage.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl : 'index.html'
    });

});
```

when i load '/' in my browser nothins is happening same with /home i dont know where did i get wrong since there is no error in my console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template for a route should be a partial view. Here index.html is the root of the single page app , this page should never reload (unless you want to destroy and rebootstrap the app). Try changing the templateUrl for / to a file that just has `<h2> HELLO WORLD!</h2>` and monitor the console (dev tools) for any 404 errors related to fetching the template

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with your javascript file name. In index you mentioned mainpage.js and in description its homepage.js.

Edit : Okay. Then try arranging files list like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/myAngularApp/css/mainpage.js"></script>
```

Comment: opsss sorry typo error that should be mainpage.js my bad

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by user Priyanka, the filename can be the issue. But that should produce an error on the console and according to you there was no error on the console.

The other possible reason can be the sequence in which you've imported your files. I generally sequence my files this way -

```html
<head>
  <!-- 1. External CSS Libraries likes bootstrap, jquery -->
  
  <!-- 2. My Application specific CSS files -->
  
  <!-- 3. External JS libraries like Angular, bootstrap, JQuery -->
  
  <!-- 4. My Application specific JS files like my controllers, services, directives etc.
</head>
```

Again the sequence in which you import the external JS libraries may also cause problems.

Comment: i try to do what u suggest sir manish but the problem is everytime i load '/' i always get this '#/' ?

Comment: Is the view corresponding to '/' loading properly? All URLs in angular js will  by default look like this - http://yourHost:port/#/yourRoute/anyPathParams

Comment: nope. everytime i hit "localhost/myAngularApp/" i get "localhost/myAngularApp/#/" but the the content of index.html is the one appearing in the browser

Comment: If you are seeing content of index.html on localhost/myAngularApp/#/, then there is nothing wrong with it.. That is how it is supposed to be. As I said, By default angular routes start after the /# in your URL. Since you've defined index.html as your template for '/' you see index.html on /#/ . This is expected behaviour. If you want you can remove the # from url by activating HTML5 routing mode - https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag